# Is running Burg on 15.04 possible?

Tags: grub2, software-installation, bootloader, 15.04, burg

Is it possible to have grub2 replaced with burg on Ubuntu 15.04? I had it on 14.04 but I'm struggling to get it on 15.04, does there need to be in a repository for 15.04 or something like that? If so, is there a manual method in getting it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you've tried and how it failed. That way, we won't be suggesting the same solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have two partions on the same disk, one with Windows10 and one with Ubuntu 15.04.

I followed these instructions: http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-install-burg-boot-loader-in-ubuntu-1304-and-linuxmint/
except for the part which allows you to choose boot drives (I didn't pick either of my drives). Then I ran...

```
sudo burg-install /dev/sdb
```

Note: my boot drive is 'sdb'
And then

```
sudo update-burg
```

...and tested with

```
sudo burg-emu
```

And it works! I also tried rebooting and it works fine, I can choose theme and everything.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating ubuntu and I got it back to work just by running:

```
sudo burg-install /dev/sda
```

Replacing /dev/sda for your hard drive and then:

```
sudo burg-update
```

NOTE: If you installed BURG using **ppa:n-muench/burg** apt repo, you will get 404 errors when doing apt-get update (not a big deal but a bit annoying for me). To fix this go to **Software & Updates**, and under **Other Software** tab, edit that repo and change **Distribution** from 'vivid' to 'utopic'.

Comment: Thank you Juan, I got that right, but now if enter `burg-emu` , I can't change the theme nor can I see a theme, although I can change only one theme(debian) in *grub-customizer* . Also if I try to change a theme in *grub-customizer it says there's no *theme.txt* detected so I appended theme to theme.txt so the error would stop coming up but the theme would never show up in burg-emu ; but if I restart I _can_ see the *debian* theme but there's no option to change a theme